# divs don't consume the full width in mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have simple webpage with header and footer.

This is roughly the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    @RenderSection("HtmlHeadTags", false)

    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @RenderSection("Analytics", false)
    @RenderSection("NortonSafe", false)
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <header>
<div id="header-navbar">
    <div id="header-navbar-active">
        <a id="websiteLogo" href="/">
            <img src="/Content/ankol-logo.png" alt="logo" />
        </a>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
        </header>
        <div id="body-content">
            @RenderSection("scripts_body", required: false)
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <footer>
    <p id="footer-links">
        <a href="/Info/About">about</a>&nbsp;
        <a href="/Info/Terms">terms</a>&nbsp;
        <a href="/Contact/">contact</a>
    </p>
    <p id="footer-copyright">2017 &copy;</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

</body>
</html>
```

with following (relevant) css parts:

```
#header-navbar {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #3F51B5;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: large;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}


#footer-navbar {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #3F51B5;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: large;
    margin-top: 70px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Now, while in pc browser both header and consume 100% of the width of the window, in mobile browser the header and the footer consume only part of the width (I have Android, but checked it on several emulators on Edge and all show the same results)
[image]

The red box is the header and the green box is the footer.

What might be the reason for that?? can anyone refer me to a good tutorial about the differences between pc browser and mobile browser? thanks.

Comment: Try put position: absolute on both. There's no need to be relative into these structures.

Comment: @CarlosAlexandre I tried it before and tried it again now. "absolute" has no effect. Thank you.

Comment: Can you put your code into CodePen to help?

Comment: @CarlosAlexandre I never did it before. I'll try now. Will let you know when I'm done. Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ use normalize,css to remove browser specific paddings, margins, etc.

Comment: @CarlosAlexandre Thank you for your help! here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/assafdsb/pen/VbVMBm I hope it works fine.

Comment: @OlegMarkoff Hi. I'm using modernizr-2.6.2.js. Does it not have the same effect?

Comment: Try put witdth: 100%; in html and body.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this style:

```
body {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
}
```